# What does the yellow highlighting of an imports clause in Android Studio signify?

Tags: import, intellij-idea, annotations, android-studio, gson

As you can see here:

[image]

...one of my "imports" seems to have "[the yaller janders](http://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/lit/huckleberry-finn/chapter-28/page_4.html)"

What does that mean?

Comment: You, sir, source your dialect like a boss.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's annotation class import, e.g. somewhere in your source file you have "@SerializedName"

[Annotation JavaDoc](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: Thanks for the simple, but correct, answer!

Just FYI, the link is broken.